# I forgot the semicolon ";" in a MySQL Terminal query. How do I exit?

Tags: mysql, sql, macos, terminal

Sometimes I forget to end my SQL query with a semicolon ";" in my Mac Terminal. When this happens, the Terminal sets a `->` at the beginning and I am not able to exit this or to run any other SQL commands.

How can I exit from this?

Comment: Wouldn't just typing a `;` do it? MySQL should ignore all spaces and newlines between the end of the query and the semicolon.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You are unaware of the 5 different quote modes of the mysql terminal.  I suggest you review them:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/entering-queries.html

**Relevant parts of the above link:**

The following table shows each of the prompts you may see and summarizes what they mean about the state that mysql is in.

```
Prompt  Meaning
mysql>  Ready for new command.

->      Waiting for next line of multiple-line command.

'>      Waiting for next line, waiting for completion of a string 
        that began with a single quote (“'”).

">      Waiting for next line, waiting for completion of a string 
        that began with a double quote (“"”).

`>      Waiting for next line, waiting for completion of an 
        identifier that began with a backtick (“`”).

/*>     Waiting for next line, waiting for completion of a 
        comment that began with /*.
```

In the MySQL 5.0 series, the `/*>` prompt was implemented in MySQL 5.0.6.

Multiple-line statements commonly occur by accident when you intend to issue a command on a single line, but forget the terminating semicolon. In this case, mysql waits for more input:

```
mysql> SELECT USER()
    ->
```

If this happens to you (you think you've entered a statement but the only response is a -> prompt), most likely mysql is waiting for the semicolon. If you don't notice what the prompt is telling you, you might sit there for a while before realizing what you need to do. Enter a semicolon to complete the statement, and mysql executes it:

**TLDR:**

To exit, type `\c`, `;`, `ctrl-c` or `ctrl-d`.  If all of those fail, get out of the quote mode you are in by typing `'<enter>`, `"<enter>`, or `*/<enter>`

Answer (score 9):

Just type \c to clear the current input statement

Answer (score 6):

Just type ";" and hit enter.  You can use as many input lines as you like to complete a query when in command line mode. So you could do something like:

```
>SELECT
>*
>FROM
>table
>WHERE
>id=5
>;
```

if you like.

Answer (score 5):

you could try `"\q"` that worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Use either of these keyboard shortcuts: <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd>.
These can be used to instantly exit any program that is running within a command prompt.

Answer (score -1):

use ctrl+c and it will go to the next line.

Comment: That kills most programs, what isn't the purpose here. A simple `;` then return should answer the problem here.