# How to return to mysql> prompt after making a typo in SQL command?

Tags: sql

As a beginner in SQL, I accidentally made a typo while writing an SQL command, and now I find myself unable to return to the `mysql>` line.

[image: m]

How can I get back to the `mysql>` prompt?

Comment: Usually, pressing `Ctrl` +`c` gets out of the situation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I forgot the semicolon ";" in a MySQL Terminal query. How do I exit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12373772/i-forgot-the-semicolon-in-a-mysql-terminal-query-how-do-i-exit)

Comment: More generic, but covers all cases including this one. Including typing `'<enter>` and ctrl+C and ctrl+D there.

Answer (score 2):

In the example you posted the prompt was waiting for completion of a string that began with a single quote ('). You can see it from the different prompt.

Each prompt indicates what it's waiting for, as explained here:

| Prompt | Meaning |
| --- | --- |
| mysql> | Ready for new query |
| -> | Waiting for next line of multiple-line query |
| '> | Waiting for next line, waiting for completion of a string that began with a single quote (') |
| "> | Waiting for next line, waiting for completion of a string that began with a double quote (") |
| `> | Waiting for next line, waiting for completion of an identifier that began with a backtick (`) |
| /*> | Waiting for next line, waiting for completion of a comment that began with /* |

[Source](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/entering-queries.html#idm46728034760832)

However, usually you can safely exit the input by hitting `Ctrl+c`

Possible duplicate of:
[mysql command line stuck on "->"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69317418/mysql-command-line-stuck-on)